# Solve Error without installing PostgreSQL on Mac? dyld: Library not loaded: libpq.5.dylib

Tags: mac, database, sql, postgresql, homebrew

I am using a Mac OS X software called TablePlus which throws an error when trying to perform a backup of a PostgreSQL 13 database that is running inside a Docker container.

> dyld: Library not loaded: libpq.5.dylib

Is it possible to install this missing library for PostgreSQL without having to install the entire PostgreSQL server software, which will happen if we do `brew install pg`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this was asked and answered over on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244778/where-do-i-get-libpq-source

You might need some familiarity with compiling open-source SW, but there are brief instructions in the answer and the comments under it.